# How to implement a text with vertical direction?

Tags: flutter

I want to implement a text with the TextDirection from top to bottom, but the TextDirection has only two options.

```
enum TextDirection {
  /// The text flows from right to left (e.g. Arabic, Hebrew).
  rtl,

  /// The text flows from left to right (e.g., English, French).
  ltr,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either method will work

```
Center(
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
          RotatedBox(
            child: Text("rotated"),
            quarterTurns: 3,
          ),
          Divider(),
          Column(
            children: "stacked".split('').map((c) => Text(c)).toList(),
          )
        ]),
      )
```

One is rotating the text. Other is stacking characters in column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RotatedBox](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html).

```
RotatedBox(
    quarterTurns: 1, 
    child: Text("Hello")
),
```